Customize y-axis
I have a few charts with data and I want the y-axis to autofit to the data + a buffer of 10%.
The customize tools don't have this option. I don't have any coding background, but with the help of ChatGPT I made this custom script that is yet to work:
function setDynamicYAxis() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // Assumes the chart you want to edit is the first one
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
   
  // Find the maximum value in the data range
  var maxValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = values[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  // Set the new max value with a buffer (e.g., 10% higher)
  var buffer = maxValue * 0.1;
  var newMax = maxValue + buffer;

  // Modify the chart's y-axis maximum value
  var updatedChart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis.maxValue', newMax)
    .build();

  sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
}


You can get the min or max by flattening the matrix.


const values = [
  [1, 3, 8],
  [2, 9, 5],
  [7, 4, 0]
];

const flattenedValues = values.flatMap(x => x);
const min = Math.min(...flattenedValues);
const max = Math.max(...flattenedValues);

console.log({ min, max });



Question: What does your dataset look like? I don't think you want the x-axis data in your range. Are you plotting multiple y-axis in one chart?
If your range includes headers you will have to slice them off:
// Find the maximum value in the data range (exclude headers)
var maxValue = Math.max(...flattenedValues = values.slice(1).flatMap(x => x));

Here is the working code (verified)
function setDynamicYAxis() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // Assumes the chart you want to edit is the first one
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
   
  // Find the maximum value in the data range (exclude headers)
  var maxValue = Math.max(...flattenedValues = values.slice(1).flatMap(x => x));

  // Set the new max value with a buffer (e.g., 10% higher)
  var buffer = maxValue * 0.1;
  var newMax = maxValue + buffer;

  // Modify the chart's y-axis maximum value
  var updatedChart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis.maxValue', newMax)
    .build();

  sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
}

Here is my sheet dataset that my chart used as a range:



x
y




1
6


2
7


3
3


4
99


5
9


6
3


7
2


8
1


9
7


10
4



Here is the output:

Note: The buffer is only used when setting the newMax, so you could remove this assignment and write this instead:
// Set the new max value with a buffer (e.g., 10% higher)
var newMax = Math.ceil(maxValue * 1.1);

